# My Java SQL Update statement is not updating my database, and I don't know if it's a problem with the statement or the connection

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am connecting my Java Program to a database stored in the program folder, and I am having users answer quiz questions and I want the results to be stored in the database. The Update statement is not working, and I don't know if it's a problem with the actual statement or the database connection.

I've tried creating a new database with the same tables and reconnecting to that database, but nothing seems to be working.

```
//database connection class
public class databaseConnection {
    public static Connection dbConnector() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Connection conn = DriverManager
                    .getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:D:\\Users\\mariammahmoud\\eclipse-workspace\\ia_2019_final\\testjava.db");
            return conn;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}

public class student {

    public static final String DB_NAME = "testjava.db";

    public static final String TABLE_STUDENTS = "students";

    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_GRADE = "grade";
    public static final String COLUMN_RESULTS = "results";
    public static final String COLUMN_EVENTS = "events";
    public static final String COLUMN_USERNAME = "username";

    public void main() {
        try {
            String user_name = login_student.sendQuiz();
            Connection conn = databaseConnection.dbConnector();
            ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>(15);
            instructions();
            questions(results);
            results.trimToSize();

            System.out.println("Here are the events that you should consider competing in:");
            System.out.println(results);

            String separator = ",";

            int total = results.size() * separator.length();
            for (String finalResults : results) {
                total += finalResults.length();
            }

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(total);
            for (String finalResults : results) {
                sb.append(separator).append(finalResults);
            }

            String resultsDatabase = sb.substring(separator.length());
            String sql = "UPDATE students SET events = ? WHERE username = " +user_name;
            PreparedStatement myStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            myStmt.setString(1, resultsDatabase);

            myStmt.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong:" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I expected the update statement to update the testjava.db database, but everything is staying the same. What should I do? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that while you wisely used a prepared statement in your code for the update, you never actually used it for the `username` column in the `WHERE` clause.  Hence, the query you are executing currently won't be interpreted as comparing some input against `username`.  Rather, the `username` value will be interpreted as a column.  Try this version:

```
String resultsDatabase = sb.substring(separator.length());
String sql = "UPDATE students SET events = ? WHERE username = ?";
PreparedStatement myStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
myStmt.setString(1, resultsDatabase);
myStmt.setString(2, user_name);
myStmt.executeUpdate();
```

Note that you *could* have just tried the following:

```
String sql = "UPDATE students SET events = ? WHERE username = '" + user_name + "'";
```

But, please bind a value to a `?` placeholder instead, as I have suggested above.  One benefit of using statements is that it frees you from having to worry about how to escape your data in the query.